# Error w/ Webpack Server

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, stylus

So I'm not really sure what's wrong, and I've looked into other solutions but none of them work. I've also looked at other similar issues and I still can't fix. Anyone have any ideas?

```
 ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 
 main.js
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'main.js' in 
 '/Users/11reed/Desktop/sty-fg'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 main.js
```

here is my config

```
 module.exports ={
    entry: 'main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'sty-fg.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
            test: /\.styl$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the file `main.js` exist? Does it exist in the same path as the webpack config?

Comment: Yeah, it does. That's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think basically webpack can't find main.js. Looks like you are missing a loader for js and a resolve for .js like so:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  }
  module:{
    loaders:[
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        { // existing
          test: /\.styl$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader"
        }
    ],
}
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/